# Replacing variable substring

Tags: iphone, ios, parsing

I have this string: `<div id="attachment_16696" class="wp-caption alignnone" style="width: 460px">`

And I want to have:  `<div id="attachment_16696" class="wp-caption alignnone" style="width: 275px">`

I works almost. The only issue is, when its for example `1000px`, because it doesnt match it doesnt work, How can I handle if it is not `460px` and I want to have it `260px` ?

Comment: why not do, replaceString 460 with 260?

Comment: because content is variable, it is not anytime 460

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code uses the [NSRegularExpression](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class to replace the width style attribute of a divs HTML markup when supplied in the format you specified:

```
// Takes Div markup in the following formats:
// <div id="something" class="something" style="width: Xpx">
// <div id="something" class="something" width="X">
// And replaces X with desired value.
- (NSString *)setDivMarkup:(NSString *)markup width:(NSInteger)width
{
    NSString *regexToReplaceWidth = @"width(:|=)(\")?\\s*\\d+\\s*(px)?";

    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regexToReplaceWidth
                                                                           options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                             error:&error];

    return [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:markup
                                           options:0
                                             range:NSMakeRange(0, markup.length)
                                      withTemplate:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"width$1$2%d$3", width]];
}
```

Comment: I would suggest using \s* like in mine, rather than a space. But otherwise looks good I think.

Comment: @crimson_penguin Makes a good point. Since any number of whitespace between 'width:' and its associated number is still valid markup you may want to replace the regular expression with the following: `NSString *regexToReplaceWidth = @"width:\\s*\\d+px";`.

Comment: Works very good, but there is one more problem: Sometimes the width is styled like `width="460"`.  I tried this regex but it doesn´t work: 
NSString *regexToReplaceWidth = @"width=\"\\d\"";

Comment: Well this makes things significantly more complicated. I assume when it is in that format it is its own standalone attribute as opposed to within the 'style' attribute e.g.: `<div id="attachment_16696" class="wp-caption alignnone" width="460">` and as such will require the double quotes around the value to remain valid markup?

Comment: Yes, so  I can't change that ?

Comment: @Supporter_04 No no, it just makes things more complicated. Give me 5 minutes ;]

Comment: @Supporter_04 Okay, it took me a little longer than 5 minutes =P. See the revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex: `string.replace(/width:\s*\d+px/, 'width: 275px')`

EDIT:
On second thought, if this is only part of a much bigger string, you probably don't want to replace all widths with `275px` (or `260px`). You should still use a regex, but I'm not sure exactly what it would be looking for without seeing the context that this is in, and knowing what you do and don't want to replace.

Comment: Yeah, this didn't actually specify a language. I was thinking "wait, how is this iPhone related?", but for some reason I assumed it was javascript, because it was operating on HTML.

Comment: If you do happen to be using javascript, or someone else is reading this, the usage of the above code is: <code>string</code> is the string you want to run the replacement on, and it'll return the result.